# php4 vs php5 support

Tags: php, compare, php4

Hello I'm developing an open source software and it requires PHP5.I made a version for PHP4.I want to know which is better to make the official release for php4 or to continue with the php5 support only and post a php4 version (as alternative).

The reason that I hesitate is because the php4 version is a bit slower, bigger and it uses more memory usage, but it has bigger range for using.

Comment: Dont support php4 at all would be my suggestion :-)

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310419/what-version-of-php-is-considered-standard-for-most-web-hosts/6310517#6310517

Comment: There's absolutely no reasons to support PHP4 anymore.

Comment: Thanks about the comments! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just stick with PHP5 only.

Who still uses v4 anyway ;)

Don't try to support both since it would mean more work for you :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP4 isn't official supported anymore, so pure PHP5 version makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

PHP4 end of life announcement was made 3 years ago.

http://developers.slashdot.org/story/07/07/14/0646216/PHP-4-End-of-Life-Announcement